# opengles offsetting texture co-ordinates in a shader

Tags: opengl-es, shader

I'm using a texture altas and this vertex shader to render a texture on a quad:

```
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
    "attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
    "attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
    "varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
    "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
    "uniform vec4 u_newColor;" +

    "void main() {" +
    "  float offset = 0.33;" +
    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
    "  v_texCoord.x = a_texCoord.x + offset;" +
    "  v_texCoord.y = a_texCoord.y + offset;" +
    "  v_Color = u_newColor;" + 
    "}";
```

Everything is working fine and I render a third in to the texture showing a middle tile of 9 in the atlas. Except I want 'offset' to be a variable i.e. I want to change it depending on which 'tile' I need in the texture atlas.

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a uniform and use that:

```
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
"attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
"attribute vec4 a_Color;" +
"attribute vec2 a_texCoord;" +
"varying vec4 v_Color;" + 
"varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
"uniform vec4 u_newColor;" +
"uniform vec2 u_offset ;" + //vec2 so there is a x and y component that you can set

"void main() {" +
"  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
"  v_texCoord = a_texCoord + u_offset;" +
"  v_Color = u_newColor;" + 
"}";
```

and you set the uniform with

```
glUniform2f(u_offset_location, xTile, yTile);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is exactly what I was trying, however the texture is no longer visible, regardless of the values I set. I did read somewhere that the 'offset' has to be a constant?

Comment: the offset should be between 0 and 1, to get the result you originally had try `0.33, 0.33` for the `xTile` and `yTile` values